# Creating python registration with pre-built template

Tags: python, html, django, python-3.x

I've been working with django for a week or two now. I had made a template wit css styling before I started working on my django project. I made signup and signin template but I found that there's no way to link fields with backend and I have to create form in django first. This is my html template but I'm unable to see the django form in the

signup.html

```html
<form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}

    <fieldset class='form-group'>
        <legend class='border-bottom-mb mb-4'>Join Today</legend>
        {{ form.as_p }}

    </fieldset>
    <div class='form-group'>
        <button type="submit" class="btn-submit">Sign Up</button>
        <br>
    </div>
    <div class="border-top pt-3">
        <small class="text-muted">
            Already have an account? 
            <a class="ml-2" href="#">Sign In</a>
        <small>
    </div>
</form>
```

views.py (users app)

```
def signup(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            messages.success(request, f'Account created for {username}')
            return redirect('web-home')
    else:
        form = UserCreationForm()
        return render(request, 'users/signup.html', {'forms': form})
```

urls.py(django project file)

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from users import views as users_view
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('signup/', users_view.signup, name='signup'),
    path('', include('web_home.urls')),
]
```

How can I make my pre-built template with CSS styling use the Django registration functionality?

Comment: Try [django-widget-tweaks](https://github.com/jazzband/django-widget-tweaks)

Comment: you are not saving the form if it is valid. you need to call `form.save()` inside of `if form.is_valid():`

Answer (score 0):

> I'm unable to see the django form in the `signup.html`

You are using the `forms` as a context variable, but have `form` in your template; change your template as:

```
<form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}

    <fieldset class='form-group'>
        <legend class='border-bottom-mb mb-4'>Join Today</legend>
        {{ forms.as_p }}

    </fieldset>
    <div class='form-group'>
        <button type="submit" class="btn-submit">Sign Up</button>
        <br>
    </div>
    <div class="border-top pt-3">
        <small class="text-muted">
            Already have an account? 
            <a class="ml-2" href="#">Sign In</a>
        <small>
    </div>
</form>
```

> How can I make my pre-built template with CSS styling use the Django registration functionality?

Try [django-widget-tweaks](https://github.com/jazzband/django-widget-tweaks)